# Unmarried keeping vows/performing vratas

Tags: marriage, vrata

Is it allowed for the unmarried boy or girl to perform the vratas--e.g. satyanarayana vrara,

Parvati performed penance and vratas to attain Shiva as her husband. But is this because she was advised by Narada and permitted by her father?

Comment: Haritalika vrat can be observed by a unmarried  woman , to attain  a good husband (by the blessings of Goddess Parvati)

Comment: I was told that these vrat are ok for unmarried women, esp the Parvati/Shiv one for future good marriage.

Comment: Some of these may not be ok, and hence my question. Unmarried girl is father's responsibility and hence father should be performing vrata. He may give permission to the maiden if he can't perform and then it may be ok. Similarly, unmarried boy is in brahmacharya mode and doesn't have ways to complete the vrata steps like feeding Brahmanas or cooking food.